# How should I include an external .js file in my Angular 2 project?

Tags: google-app-engine, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2's TypeScript API with webpack to create a browser app. Unfortunately one of my components requires the use of functions in an external .js file from the [App Engine Channel API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/javascript).

Unlike my other .js dependencies I don't think I can precompile this .js file in my webpack bundle because I believe it is dynamically generated.

What's the most appropriate way to load the file into my app and use it? How can I avoid async loading issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend on what [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39262164/1961059) already pointed out:

Yes, you can indeed just load them in the head section of your HTML file above where you load your bundle/Angular 2 project.

And in the component, where you want to use that code you could just write the declaration of the `goog` variable above your `Component` class:

```ts
declare var goog: any;
```

And inside your component you can now use all the methods you want, just without auto-completion.

If you want auto-completion you could install the TypeScript definition files via npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gae.channel.api

Or just place it in your `typings` folder right away and reference it at the top of your component file with:

```ts
/// <reference path="../typings/gae.channel.api.d.ts" />
```

**gae.channel.api.d.ts:**

```ts
// Type definitions for GoogleAppEngine's Channel API
// Project: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/javascript
// Definitions by: vvakame <https://github.com/vvakame>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

declare namespace goog.appengine {
    export class Channel {
        constructor(token: string);
        open(handler?: Function): Socket;
    }

    export class Socket {
        close(): void;
        onopen: () => void;
        onmessage: (message: any) => void;
        onerror: Function;
        onclose: () => void;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its kind of primitive but you can just place your js files in your html file above where you load your bundle.